# Cutting and dimensioning Furring Strips

Tags: roofing

Great explanation on the flat roof sloping. The question I have is if my roof is 6 x 7.5 m and the main slope goes 90 degrees across the joists (that is, the joists are across the narrow part of the roof and the drain is at the far end of the longest dimension), do I need to be concerned about cutting the furring strips and the required angle (direction of the joists) but as well the change in angle across the slope. Such a two dimensional cut to ensure the paneling would be supported only by the edge of the furring strips. Hope that makes sense. Regards

No wonder you didn't understand the question. whith your edit you put the entire message out of context.

Comment: You say, “the paneling would be supported only by the edge of the furring strips”. Are the furring strips installed vertically? (Paneling??? I thought you were asking about joists?)

Comment: @Kevin - it's not clear what "Great explanation" you're referring to. You've asked a fresh question here, and it's not linked to any other question which you may have been reading at the time. Stack Exchange sites don't just chain messages onto the end of a thread like other forum-type sites you may be used to. Each question should have sufficient detail to stand on its own.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need a lot more info before we have any chance of helping you. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: ok, I will start over. I have a flat roof and it needs to have a slope for run off. I this case the slope needs to go to one corner. So if I simply do a staight cut on the furring strips to get the angle in one direction and adjust the thickness for the other direction the planking will rest on the edge of the firring strips i.e not make full contact

Comment: Please revise your post. Don't attempt to change its direction in a comment. That's just weird. :)